# macos - local port redirection using pfctl and syntax errors

Tags: osx, openbsd, filter, pf, packet

I am running MacOS(really BSD), and I want to redirect certain traffic over an ssh tunnel using a a local forward.  Seems easy enough, but I am repeatedly blocked by the ambiguous "/etc/pf.conf:29: syntax error" message at every turn.  I must have gone through 30 iterations of the rule by now.  Additionally, I have read the relevant OpenBSD packet filter information regarding syntax and redirection.  Am at quiet the loss, and seek the help of someone smarter than myself about the BSD packet filter.

The goal is to take any traffic sourcing from my local machine destined to a machine on the internet to port 1234 and redirect the traffic to 127.0.0.1:1234.  My specific os is OS X 10.10.2 Yosemite.

Here is the latest iteration of the rule which causes pfctl to return "syntax error"

`pass out quick on en6 from any to en6 port 1234 rdr-to 127.0.0.1 port 1234`

Based on the documentation and other random blogs on the Internet, this rule looks correct; pfctl however, disagrees.

The breakdown based on my understanding of the documentation is:

`pass` - the action to pass the traffic

`out` - the direction of traffic flow

`quick` - if the packet matches this rule, then consider this the last rule in the chain

`on en6` - the interface on which to apply the rule

`from any` - the source of the packet (should always be my machine)

`to en6 port 1234` - to anything on the interface destined for port 1234

`rdr-to 127.0.0.1 port 1234` - redirect the packet to this interface

Comment: Please update your post and put complete your rules into your post

Comment: I posted a complete rule did I not?  I'm certain

"pass out quick on en6 from any to en6 port 1234 rdr-to 127.0.0.1 port 1234"

is a complete rule.  If not, perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: I update my anwer, you can test it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it :

```
rdr pass quick on $ext_inf inet proto tcp from any to any port 1394 -> $target port 1394
```

Comment: I played a little more with the setup the provided rule.

'rdr on $ext_inf inet proto tcp to port 1394 -> $target port 1394'

The above rule ended up working.  Apperently 'pass' and 'quick' are not okay in the rule.

Comment: It's good , you make me happy.

Comment: By the way, OpenBSD syntax splited into 3 syntax : 1) 'keep state' becoming the default in OpenBSD 4.1 -- but everybody's
    forgotten about that one, mainly because FreeBSD and NetBSD back
then
    adopted the change relatively quickly

Comment: 2) the NAT rewrite and syntax change (nat-to, rdr-to etc) in 4.7 --
    old rule sets will break, in almost all cases easily fixable, and
    the new syntax is lots more flexible anyway (and the reason The
    Book of PF needed a second edition)

Comment: 3) the introduction of new queueing system in 5.5 - again an
    opportunity to make the rulse more readable and offering more
    flexibility, at the cost of at least some (mostly quite easy)
    conversion. (and the reason there is a third edition of that book)

Comment: And higher 5.5 doesn't any probelm i have a good doc for you : Its last change is 2105 : http://home.nuug.no/~peter/pf/en/index.html